# Android studio and SDK installing error

Tags: android-studio

using Android studio 3.1.2

I installed JDK last version , then installed Android studio 3.1.2 . when I run android studio for a fist time , it ask me about sdk path and the massage is "if you dont have the android SDK you can optain it from this link.".

Error shortcut:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_DyaOYIOzVJ79ixVpuoViZUyAt-s2b9s/view?usp=sharing

I downloaded the SDK tool pacake (sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zipf) from that link(https://developer.android.com/studio/) but what is the next step ?

when i tried download SDK from SDK manager it also shows this error massage "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted."

Error shortcut:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HurRBB90wPUgzH1V31L5930QEbxRB_Bq/view?usp=sharing

How can I fix this problem ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Sdk from here https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads and Extract this zip to C:\users\administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk. Do not forget to replace "administrator" by your current user on windows.

1. Open Android studio and click on configure. See here [Configure button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb55v.png)
2. Click on Sdk Manager
3. Set the Sdk Path to  C:\users\administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
4. Update your android studio now. Go to About -> Check for Updates.

Comment: I have recently moved my android studio from ubuntu to windows due to red error"cannot resolve symbol" but now everything works fine on windows.